# Where is the Brotherhood of Steel's missing laser pistol?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-new-vegas

I have the unmarked side quest where I need to find a laser pistol in Scorpion Gulch. I have gotten tips where they say it's near a dead body, and I remember finding that body and looting it but I can't find the body again (possibly it vanished since I looted it completely?) Are there any tips on where to find this gun?

(PS. I would check the wiki if I had a chance to get on it, but I have no pc that is allowed on there.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pistol is not on the corpse, but on a rock near it. Quoting directly from [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Missing_Laser_Pistol_(quest)):

> Approaching the gulch on foot doesn't take that long, and you should come across a rock with a Dead Prospector leaning against it. Go east-southeast from here into a small valley. Pick up the missing laser pistol sitting on top of the rock in the center (be aware that picking it up often causes 6 or more Bark scorpion hunters and a Giant radscorpion to appear even if you have cleared out the area) and return it to the quartermaster for a reward.

Comment: i have had a few looks around but i can't find the body. i believe i looted it and thus made it dissapear. i have looked on the ground but i'm failing to find the pistol without the body. any other tips you have that could make it easier?

Comment: Perhaps the pistol has disappeared due to a bug. Do you have a save file from before you started the quest? You may also try fast traveling to Scorpion Gulch and have a look around.
EDIT: I've just seen in the wiki ( http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpion_Gulch#Notable_Loot ) that the pistol only spawns if you talk to Initiate Stanton after starting the quest. Try speaking to him and exhausting the conversation tree.